# How to mount ISO as DVD by virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, mount, dvd, iso-image, windows-98

I am trying to run an old program written for win98. I downloaded the win98 vmware image from here: https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-98/98-second-edition I am able to start the system, but every time it installs mouse drivers. I guess I need to create a snapshot to make the changes permanent, but I don't have experience with virtual machines.

I wrote an iso file from the cd of the program. It contains some sort of setup. Is it possible to mount this iso file into the system and install it on the win98? If so, how can I do that? I tried to add an optical drive, I selected the iso file, but it does not show up under win98. :S

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a comment about what's wrong with this question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected settings/storage and added a new SCSI controller to the virtual machine. In that controller I added an optical drive with BusLogic. After that I went to the start/settings/control-panel on win98 and added a new hardware. After a few tries and a restart, the win98 recognized the disc and I was able to use it.

I managed to install my program after mounting the ISO file.

It required 256 colors at least. So I installed a display driver from here: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!ALiY0wuD0edfrD0&id=108BFF45BB25F74A!18183&cid=108BFF45BB25F74A According to ESET Smart Security it does not contain a virus. The first and the second restart did not work, but at third restart Win98 managed to boot up. After that I changed the resolution to 1024x768 and set the color to 16 bit.

Done.